# Formula excel SOMASE

Tags: microsoft-excel

Coloquei esta fórmula no Excel e não deu certo, porque?

```
=SOMASE(E2:E158;"<=4>=10";B2:B158)
```

Não consigo colocar que seja maior que 4 e menor que 10, ele só aceita uma das duas hipóteses... como fazer?

Answer (score 6):

Para vários critérios, você deve usar o `SOMASES`

```
=SOMASES(B2:B158;E2:E158;">=4";E2:E158;"<=10")
```

**Sintaxe:**

```
=SOMASES( intervalo_soma, critérios_intervalo1, critérios1, [critérios_intervalo2, critérios2], ...).
```